# How do I add script files to a Raspberry Pi filesystem using a custom Yocto recipe?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto, ppp

I have a working [Yocto](http://www.yoctoproject.org/) image for a RaspberryPi3.  I want to add 3 script files /etc/ppp/peers/.  I would have thought that adding non-compiled files to the root file-system was a fairly generic thing to do but the only examples I can find are using compiled files and inheriting the autotools recipe.

Is there an example of how to add text files or script files to a Yocto root filesystem this somewhere?
Either a How To write up or an existing recipe that takes a set of text files and places them onto the target's rootfs.

I must be missing something because I cannot get the file files onto the system.
I tried using do_deploy, but that puts files into my ../tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi3/etc/ppp/ which would be helpful for scripts to aid in image deployment.  It is not what I want though as the scripts need to be on the target.

Running a do_install() with or without a blank do_compile() has not resulted in things getting onto the target either.  Unless there is something about using ${sysconfdir} or ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} or ${S} or ${D} or ${DEPLOYDIR} or ${WORKDIR} which is particular to the Pi.  I'd provide an example of my script but having changed it so many times in the last two days there is not much worth of sharing just one iteration.

Anything that resembles the following with; 
 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} possibly substituted for ${D} or missing
 do_install replaced with do_deploy.
There are probably other permutations that I have tried.

```
#
# Copy the ppp script files for <vendor> chips to the target filesystem
# These files are based on the details provided in 
#

SUMMARY = "PPP Scripts for ..."
SECTION = "net"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
DESCRIPTION = "A set of Linux PPP scripts blar blar"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "ppp"

SRC_URI += "file://<provider>-ppp"
SRC_URI += "file://<provider>-chat-connect"
SRC_URI += "file://<provider>-chat-disconnect"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

#PACKAGES =+ "${PN} ${PN}-staticdev"

#DEPLOYDIR = "${WORKDIR}/deploy-${PN}"

#D = "${DEPLOYDIR}"

inherit allarch

# Install script on target's root file-system
do_install () {
    # Install init script and default settings
    install -d ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}
    install -d ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/
    install -d ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/<provider>-ppp ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/<provider>-chat-connect ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/<provider>-chat-disconnect ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/
}

# Mark the files which are part of this package
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/ppp/"
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/"
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/<provider>-ppp"
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/<provider>-chat-connect"
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers/<provider>-chat-disconnect"
```

I can find a lot of helloworld.c and automate examples.  There must be some basic ones for adding scripts somewhere?  My googlefu is very weak, I blame a lingering cold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/<provider>-ppp ${D}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peer` in your recipe. Have you added the resulting package to your image recipe? You could look at `${WORKDIR}/packages-split/${PN}` to confirm that your files have been properly packaged.

Comment: Thank you. The use of `${D}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peer` instead of `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}/ppp/peers` was the key issue I was facing.  Know that ${WORKDIR}/packages-split/${PN} should be there and populated was also very helpful.